# iOS: performSegueWithIdentifier weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

This is totally weird behavior! I just have two view controllers, say, V1, V2. I'm trying to push V2 from V1 using `performSegueWithIdentifier` and it throws this error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e5'`

I have assigned segue identifier. I have cross checked the name of the segue, it looks perfectly alright with no spaces etc.

I tried presenting V2 using `presentViewController` method with storyboard id and it's working good, but not when I push it.

I tested another empty view controller V3 with same segue identifier(of course, I removed the identifier for V2), and it's working. So the problem is, it's throwing the error only with V2.

**EDIT**

Complete call stack:

```
2016-07-27 11:18:24.018 Sample[13254:123408] -[__NSCFNumber pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e5
2016-07-27 11:18:24.033 Sample[13254:123408] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e5'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e5dd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001068d1deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e66d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106daccfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106dac8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104f33023 -[UINavigationBar _defaultTitleFontFittingHeight:withScaleAdjustment:] + 201
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104f332ae -[UINavigationBar _defaultTitleFontWithScaleAdjustment:] + 99
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104f5e443 -[UINavigationItemView _defaultFont] + 125
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104f5e315 -[UINavigationItemView initWithNavigationItem:] + 338
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104f2cc89 -[UINavigationItem _defaultTitleView] + 125
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104f2cd2b -[UINavigationItem _titleView] + 125
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104f4e5d8 -[UINavigationBar _removeItemsFromSuperview:] + 124
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104f36718 -[UINavigationBar _setItems:transition:reset:resetOwningRelationship:] + 986
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001050175f0 -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edge:duration:] + 258
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105016f3f -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edgeIfNotNavigating:duration:] + 607
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010501587c -[UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:] + 142
    16  Sample                          0x0000000102df6783 _TFC10Sample21TPLoginViewController17viewWillDisappearfSbT_ + 195
    17  Sample                          0x0000000102df67d1 _TToFC10Sample21TPLoginViewController17viewWillDisappearfSbT_ + 49
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104fe33aa -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 947
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104fe3ac2 -[UIViewController __viewWillDisappear:] + 93
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000105013735 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1176
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000105023b9b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000105024d0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001051d3503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000104efd980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    25  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049e0c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    26  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049d508e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    27  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049d4f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    28  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049c93c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    29  QuartzCore                          0x00000001049f7086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000104e3d72e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7135
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d83301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d7922c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d786e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d780f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a9f4ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000104e42f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    37  Sample                          0x0000000102f037f2 main + 114
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001081e692d start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you add the code from the `performSegueWithIdentifier` function?

Comment: @MattLeFleur It's just this `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signup", sender: nil)` when I click a button.

Comment: You could perhaps set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `performSegueWithIdentifier` function and step through it until you find the exact line that is causing the error (more specifically in the `prepareForSegue` function if you are using it. You are perhaps calling a function/trying to reference a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that you are calling somewhere a `UIFont` method on a `NSNumber` object. Do you pass in the `viewDidLoad` of the V2? Is `prepareForSegue:` called?

Comment: I concur with Larme, `pointSize` is a property of `UIFont` or `NSFont`

Comment: @Larme No, I'm not calling `UIFont` method on `NSNumber`. I put breakpoints in `ViewDidLoad` of V2, `prepareForSegue` in V1, but it's not hitting them.

Comment: What are you trying to access `pointSize` from?

Comment: @MattLeFleur I don't know why I get that `pointSize` error. When I `presentViewController` it's working good, but not when I push it with `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Do you still think it's something with `UIFont` or `NSNumber`?

Comment: @MattLeFleur @Larme Alright, I changed `Push` to `Modal` for segue in storyboard and it's working. So the problem is only with push. (I have navigation controller for V1)

Comment: Could you show the stack trace when it crashes? Your issue is weird, I agree. Could be a "memory" issue (weak property somewhere that could lead to that error, but I don't know why only on push?)

Comment: @Larme I have updated my post with the call stack.

Comment: Are you using any custom fonts?

Comment: @Luke No, not using any custom fonts.

Comment: Is V1 or V2 embedded within UINavigation Controller ?

Comment: @MeetShah Yes, V1 is embedded with `UINavigationController` and V2 is not

Comment: Can you change both the segues to Modal instead of Push and see if it works ?

Comment: Push Segues can cause this weird Behavior as V2 will inherit V1 Nav Bar unless disabled explicitly in Storyboard or through code

Comment: Or Other way to confirm would be to remove UINavigation Controller connection to V1 temporarily and use same code.

Comment: @MeetShah You're the man! That's the error. I'm hiding navigation bar in V1. I commented the `setNavigationBarHidden` code and it worked like charm!

Comment: The stack trace says that the problem has something to do with text on the navigation bar. That might be the view controller's title. or anything else that you expect to appear in the nav bar. Can you update your question with details of that?

Comment: @MeetShah But one more doubt. Why it worked when I pushed another empty view controller V3 using push segue?